# Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher->Stop() crashes when scanning

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-cx

I am writing a JNI DLL using C++ to provide our Java application with a way to access Bluetooth LE devices on Windows 10 and macOS. It uses C++/CX to access Bluetooth LE objects on Windows 10 and Objective-C++ to access the equivalent on macOS. This question focuses on a crash I'm experiencing on Windows 10, however, so the macOS-specific code will not be factored in. This crash occurs when using my DLL via JNI or via separate C exports (using a command line test app I wrote to simplify debugging).

Note: `CentralManagerCppCxShim` is a `ref class` which just calls back into `CentralManagerImpl` when events are fired.

The crash occurs when the `CentralManagerImpl` object is destroyed while the scan is running (i.e. `StartScan()` was called): when `_deviceWatcher` gets destroyed it crashes (whether I set it to `nullptr` or not makes no difference). I had a similar issue with the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` but properly removing the event handlers in the destructor made the crash go away.

Code excerpts:

CentralManagerImpl.h:

```
class CentralManagerImpl: public CentralManager
{
private:
    CentralManagerCppCxShim ^_shim;
    DeviceWatcher ^_deviceWatcher;
    BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher ^_watcher;
    EventRegistrationToken _deviceWatcherAdded;
    EventRegistrationToken _deviceWatcherRemoved;
    EventRegistrationToken _deviceWatcherUpdated;
    EventRegistrationToken _watcherReceived;
public:
    CentralManagerImpl();
    ~CentralManagerImpl();
    void StartScan();
    void StopScan();
}
```

CentralManagerImpl.cpp:

```
CentralManagerImpl::CentralManagerImpl()
{
    _shim = ref new CentralManagerCppCxShim(this);
    _deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation::CreateWatcher(BluetoothLEDevice::GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true));
    _deviceWatcherAdded = _deviceWatcher->Added += ref new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher ^, DeviceInformation ^>(_shim, &CentralManagerCppCxShim::OnDeviceAdded);
    _deviceWatcherRemoved = _deviceWatcher->Removed += ref new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher ^, DeviceInformationUpdate ^>(_shim, &CentralManagerCppCxShim::OnDeviceRemoved);
    _deviceWatcherUpdated = _deviceWatcher->Updated += ref new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher ^, DeviceInformationUpdate ^>(_shim, &CentralManagerCppCxShim::OnDeviceUpdated);
    _deviceWatcher->Stopped += ref new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher ^, Object ^>(_shim, &CentralManagerCppCxShim::OnDeviceWatcherStopped);
    _watcher = ref new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
    BluetoothLEManufacturerData ^manufacturerData = ref new BluetoothLEManufacturerData();
    manufacturerData->CompanyId = MAKEWORD(HIBYTE(OUR_COMPANY_IDENTIFIER), LOBYTE(OUR_COMPANY_IDENTIFIER));
    _watcher->AdvertisementFilter->Advertisement->ManufacturerData->Append(manufacturerData);
    _watcher->Stopped += ref new TypedEventHandler<BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher ^, BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs ^>(_shim, &CentralManagerCppCxShim::OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped);
    _watcherReceived = _watcher->Received += ref new TypedEventHandler<BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher ^, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs ^>(_shim, &CentralManagerCppCxShim::OnAdvertisementReceived);
}

CentralManagerImpl::~CentralManagerImpl()
{
    _watcher->Received -= _watcherReceived;
    _watcher = nullptr;
    _deviceWatcher->Updated -= _deviceWatcherUpdated;
    _deviceWatcher->Removed -= _deviceWatcherRemoved;
    _deviceWatcher->Added -= _deviceWatcherAdded;
    _deviceWatcher = nullptr; // this crashes :(
}

void CentralManagerImpl::StartScan()
{
    _deviceWatcher->Start();
    _watcher->Start();
}

void CentralManagerImpl::StopScan()
{
    _watcher->Stop();
    _deviceWatcher->Stop();
}
```

This is the call stack I'm getting (yes, it's nasty):

```
ntdll.dll!_TppRaiseInvalidParameter@0()
ntdll.dll!_TpPostWork@4()
cfgmgr32.dll!TQuery::CloseQuery()
cfgmgr32.dll!_DevCloseObjectQuery@4()
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.dll!Watcher<class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher2,class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformation,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformation2,class DeviceInformationServer,class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationUpdate,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformationUpdate,class DeviceInformationUpdateServer,&unsigned short const * const RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceWatcher>::Impl::EndQuery(void)
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.dll!Watcher<class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher2,class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformation,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformation2,class DeviceInformationServer,class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationUpdate,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformationUpdate,class DeviceInformationUpdateServer,&unsigned short const * const RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceWatcher>::Impl::Stop(bool)
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.dll!Watcher<class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher2,class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformation,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformation2,class DeviceInformationServer,class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationUpdate,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformationUpdate,class DeviceInformationUpdateServer,&unsigned short const * const RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceWatcher>::~Watcher<class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher2,class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformation,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformation2,class DeviceInformationServer,class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::Devic()
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.dll!Watcher<class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher2,class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformation,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformation2,class DeviceInformationServer,class Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationUpdate,struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformationUpdate,class DeviceInformationUpdateServer,&unsigned short const * const RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceWatcher>::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.dll!Microsoft::WRL::Details::RuntimeClass<struct Microsoft::WRL::Details::InterfaceList<struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher,struct Microsoft::WRL::Details::InterfaceList<struct Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceWatcher2,struct Microsoft::WRL::Details::InterfaceList<struct Windows::Foundation::IClosable,struct Microsoft::WRL::Details::InterfaceList<class Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase,class Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil> > > >,struct Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<3>,1,1,0>::Release(void)
mydll.dll!__abi_winrt_ptr_assign(void * * __ppTargetArg, const volatile Platform::Object ^ __objArg) Line 405
mydll.dll!CentralManagerImpl::~CentralManagerImpl() Line 64
[External Code] 
//…
```

Comment: *"properly removing the event handlers in the destructor made the crash go away"* - Since you know the answer already, what is your question?

Comment: It made the similar issue (with BluetootheLEAdvertisementWatcher) go away. I still get the crash with DeviceWatcher.

Comment: You don't seem to remove the `_deviceWatcher->Stopped` delegate.

Comment: I did attempt to remove the `Stopped` handler as well but it didn't prevent the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deeper investigation, I have come to the following conclusion:

The system cannot destroy the `DeviceWatcher` in the default destructor of the `CentralManagerImpl` C++ class when the DLL is being unloaded (`DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`) as the UWP worker threads have already been terminated by the system. The only working solution I found was to add a new export to my DLL for explicitly tearing down my C++ class.

I'll mark this as answered as I don't believe there's another way around this.